# How do I complete Level 02-19?

Tags: geared-2

I hate to ask for help with games like this, but I've been stuck here in *Geared 2* for quite some time.  Can anyone give me the solution?

---

[image: Geared 2: 02-19]

Comment: Geared 2? Oy, you ask a good, serious-toned question and it's for the *sequel* of a game that I could help with. Well, good luck with getting a solution nonetheless ♪

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

To get the left-cog on the right to move to the left:

1. Use the spare cog to block the down-cog from moving by placing it to the left, interlocking with the other cog.
2. Remove the existing cog. The left-cog will move to the left and the down-cog will fall.

([source](http://magitek.nu/geared/level-2-19/))

Comment: I know how it has to end up, but I can't figure out how to get the gear on the right over to the left.  Can you give me a procedural list of actions?

Comment: I've appended directions on how to get the left-cog to move left after the image.